# Why calling detoured function via original pointer works?

Tags: detours

I'm using Microsoft Detours. I'm detouring `CreateFileW()` function.

Here is shortcut of my code that attaches a detour. Error handling etc omitted.

```
    ...

    ptrTargetFunction = DetourFindFunction("kernel32.dll", "CreateFileW");

    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
   
    printf("[D] Before DetourAttach: ptrTargetFunction = %p\n", ptrTargetFunction); // 4

    PDETOUR_TRAMPOLINE pRealTrampoline;
    PVOID pRealTarget;
    PVOID pRealDetour;
    DetourAttachEx((PVOID*)&ptrTargetFunction, hook, &pRealTrampoline, &pRealTarget, &pRealDetour);
   
    printf("[D] After DetourAttach: ptrTargetFunction = %p\n", ptrTargetFunction); // 9
    printf("[D] \t pRealTrampoline = %p\n", pRealTrampoline);
    printf("[D] \t pRealTarget = %p\n", pRealTarget);
    printf("[D] \t pRealDetour = %p\n", pRealDetour);

    ...
```

Here is full code of `hook()` function. `hook()` is a detour function.

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
 
EXTERN InjectionFunction: PROC
EXTERN ptrTargetFunction: qword

hook PROC
    push rsp
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx
    push rsi
    push rdi
    push rbp
    push r8
    push r9
    push r10
    push r11
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    push r15
    call InjectionFunction
    pop r15
    pop r14
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop r11
    pop r10
    pop r9
    pop r8
    pop rbp
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    pop rsp
    mov rax, ptrTargetFunction   // 36
    push rax                     // 37
    ret                          // 38

hook ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

As I understood, Microsoft Detours will change implementation of the target function (that will be detoured (`CreateFileW`)) by replacing some of first assembler instructions by `jmp` to detour (hook()) function. It also creates trampoline function that should be called if we want to call not detoured implementation of `CreateFileW`.

At lines 4 and 9 (singled out via comment) printed address of target function is the same. Variable `ptrTargetFunction` should contain address of changed implementation of `CreateFileW`.

When detoured function is called `hook()` is invoked. In the end of the `hook()` function we call target function by placing it's address on top of the stack and executing `ret` instruction (lines 36-37).

I suppose that execution flow should be something like: `some_code`->`(detoured)CreateFileW()`->`hook()`->`(detoured)CreateFileW()`->`hook()`->... infinite circle.

During debugging I realized that there is no infinite circle. Why?

Feel free to ask any questions or ask for rewriting question because of difficulties in understanding the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

```
LONG DetourAttach(
    _Inout_ PVOID * ppPointer,
    _In_    PVOID pDetour
    );
```

> Detours replaces the first few instructions of the target function
> with an unconditional jump to the user-provided detour function.
> Instructions from the target function are placed in a trampoline. The
> address of the trampoline is placed in a target pointer.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/detours/wiki

So, as I understood, ptrTargetFunction will store pointer to trampoline.

I still don't realize why at lines 4 and 9 ptrTargetFunction has same values.